# Find row(s) that contain specific letter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a large file (csv) data which I'm trying to parse genes that contain specific letters
Example table (the actual data is 5GB and much larger matrix)

| Cell_Index | 880246 | 13694 | 491094 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCA7 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| zyg11 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ABR | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| ACAP2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| mtycap | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| zyg11 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I'm trying to rows that contain the letter "mt" in the Cell_Index column.
What I tried :

```
df = df.loc[df['Cell_Index'].str.startswith("mt", case=False)]
```

When I ran that code it gave me an error message KeyError: 'Cell_Index'

Not sure what I did wrong here.....

Answer (score 2):

Just subset the data frame directly without using `loc()`:

```py
df = df[df["Cell_Index"].str.startswith("mt", case=False)]
```

Comment: I tried doing that but got the same error message.

   3624             except TypeError:
   3625                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'Cell_Index'